# Migrating Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid App to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Have been following the instructions to migrate VS2013 proejct to VS2015 as outlined in the page:

http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/07/31/migrating-a-cordova-project-from-visual-studio-2013-to-visual-studio-2015/

and

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md

Getting some build Errors:

```
Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:11)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "LabbookMobile.jsproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:11)
```

Full Output: http://pastebin.com/uh6eMQu1

Dose anyone anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had some of the files in the wrong location in the newly created www directory. The xxxx.jsproj, taco.json and config.xml should be in the directory above the www folder.